# Is It Necessary to declare the Type of User-Defined Functions in ANY Calling Routine?

Tags: fortran

I use the Intel Visual Fortran. According to Chapmann's book, declaration of function type in the routine that calls it, is NECESSARY. But look at this piece of code,

```
module mod
implicit none
contains
function fcn ( i )
    implicit none
    integer :: fcn
    integer, intent (in) :: i
    fcn = i + 1
end function
end module

program prog
    use mod
    implicit none
    print *, fcn ( 3 )
end program
```

It runs without that declaration in the calling routine (here prog) and actually when I define its type (I mean function type) in the program prog or any other unit, it bears this error,

error #6401: The attributes of this name conflict with those made accessible by a USE statement.   [FCN]    Source1.f90 15

What is my fault? or if I am right, How can it be justified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be working with a very old copy of Chapman's book, or possibly misinterpreting what it says.  Certainly a calling routine must know the type of a called function, and in Fortran-before-90 it was the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the calling function had that information.

However, since the 90 standard and the introduction of `module`s there are other, and better, ways to provide information about the called function to the calling routine.  One of those ways is to put the called functions into a module and to `use`-associate the module.  When your program follows this approach the compiler takes care of matters. This is precisely what your code has done and it is not only correct, it is a good approach, in line with modern Fortran practice.

*association* is Fortran-standard-speak for the way(s) in which names (such as `fcn`) become associated with entities, such as the function called `fcn`.  *use-association* is the way implemented by writing `use module` in a program unit, thereby making all the names in `module` available to the unit which uses `module`.  A simple use statement makes all the entities in the module known under their module-defined names.  The `use` statement can be modified by an `only` clause, which means that only some module entities are made available.  Individual module entities can be renamed in a `use` statement, thereby associating a different name with the module entity.

The error message you get if you include a (re-)declaration of the called function's type in the calling routine arises because the compiler will only permit one declaration of the called function's type.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify the 2nd part of your sentence "One of those ways is to put the called functions into a module and to use-associate the module"?